Blender not creating keyframes automaticly when object is in the same place
Before 4.1 when I wantend for something to be in one place for a certain time I've put this in the right place with auto keying on, and then after a certain amount of frames, I just pressed G + Enter. Then the position was saved due to auto keying, and because i didn't change the coordinates (just G + Enter) it was in the same place. In  4.1 when I'm doing it nothing happens. I need to do at least small change in coordinates to create new keyframe. I know that I can always use "K" and manually add keyframe, but not the point of having enabled auto keying.
Is there any option for this to work as it used to before 4.1? Or I just need to get used to new workflow and pressing K every time :(
The same happens with scale and rotation, I always need to do at least a small change.

What's the difference if you press G or K? You have to somehow express your intention for software to do something you want. A key press seems like minimal amount of action possible, so what's the problem?

G is just pressing G and mouse click, 0.1s action. K is taking my hand away to the right side of the keyboard, then pressing K, then choosing from the list, more to do and it is also something that I would need to get used to, where before 4.1 there was already "simpler" solution that I'm used to.

You can remap the hotkey to be double press G.

OK, double G doesn't seem to work. :D It could be something else.
